# How to carry a traditional bow while hiking?

Tags: hiking, gear, archery, roving

We're planning a 4 day hike in a few months. I would like to take my bow with me to do a little roving.

How can I attach my bow to my backpack (back)?

*We are talking about an unstrung one-piece traditional hunting recurve.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use a pack similar to this one...

[image]

[RedHead Primal Bow/Rifle Pack](http://m.basspro.com/RedHead-Primal-Bow/Rifle-Pack/product/13030307014435/)

The pack is designed to carry your recurve bow (or other bow or rifle). From the item description:

> Carries rifle, crossbow, compound bow, or recurve/longbow

Comment: Nice, thanks! Do you know if there are any without camo?

Answer (score 10):

I would lash it to the side of the pack, vertically, with nylon straps that you can purchase at any outdoor sporting store. You may have a little bit of trouble walking beneath branches or fallen trees if it extends too high above you. You should also remember that a bow is considered hunting equipment and, depending on the state you are in, you can be in legal trouble if you do not have a hunting license or if you are not in season.

Comment: Thank you very much! I live in Germany and luckily a bow is considered as "sporting equipment" there by law :) (as long as you don't have broadheads attached!). Would you mind providing a picture of such nylon straps?

Comment: You can purchase something like [this](http://www.amazon.com/Country-Brook-Design%C2%AE-Polypro-Webbing/dp/B001QL2C26/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1452786699&sr=8-2&keywords=nylon+webbing) and some buckles. This way you can customize your setup. I pack a [takedown bow](http://www.amazon.com/Samick-Sage-Takedown-Recurve-60lb/dp/B00GVCEYFI/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1452786885&sr=8-1-spons&keywords=samick+sage&psc=1) that I can assemble and disassemble easily. I keep it protected and dry inside my pack and it doesn't hang on branches.

Answer (score 3):

Traditional bows can be long....ever considered a pool stick bag? Depending on personal height and whether your quiver is on the hip or back- mod straps added to hold the bow should be quick and easy