# Backpack with rifle/bow holder without camo?

Tags: hiking, archery, hunting, backpacks, bow-hunting

The [answer](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/10568/8060) to [this question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/10565/how-to-carry-a-bow-while-hiking) states that one may want to use a backpack with the possibility to attach a bow or a rifle.

> I use a pack similar to this one...
>
> [RedHead Primal Bow/Rifle Pack](http://m.basspro.com/RedHead-Primal-Bow/Rifle-Pack/product/13030307014435/)

---

[image]

---

However, I don't want to have camouflaged equipment to hike. Is there something similar without camo?

Comment: the holder seems simple enough, you could probably make one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found some! I've searched a little bit and stumbled over a few. For example the "Halti Kauris":

[image]

One is even able to remove the "rifle holder" and use it as a completely common backpack.

Or the "Wisport Forester":

[image]

Also I came across [these beauties](https://www.etsy.com/shop/MadeOfLeather):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

But as wonderful as they are, they are expensive and the backpacks quite small.

Answer (score 6):

If your reason for not wanting camo is that you want to be obvious (maybe to other hunters so you don't get shot) then you can always flash a backpack with reflective material, or use a hi vis pack cover such as those recommended for cyclists.

Home-modding a rucksack to incorporate the barrel ties and stock pocket probably wouldn't take you too long if you wanted to turn your favourite pack into one able to carry a gun.

If it is purely for fashion reasons, then you are at the mercy of the manufacturers, who will make those they think will sell - and if camo packs are the big sellers then that is what you will find.

Comment: Some backpacks also come with bright raincovers built in.

Answer (score 0):

I use this bow pack when I want a lightweight solution. Here is a link: http://www.cabelas.com/product/hunting/archery/archery-cases-holders/bow-slings-holsters%7C/pc/104791680/c/104693580/sc/104256180/i/103987080/cabela-s-bow-carrier-sling/1587543.uts?destination=%2Fcategory%2FBow-Slings-Holsters%2F103987080.uts

[image: bow pack]

Comment: The question specifies they don't want camo.

Comment: It also comes in black on Cabelas website, but I didn't see an image for it.

Comment: It might be a good idea to include more details in your question, like the name of the pack and the availability of the pack in black.